# Trouble importing *.jar to a Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, jar

I need to know if having a Maven project, I can import external (*.jar)'s without generating a Maven dependency (POM), just importing them in the project build path.

I'm finding troubles trying to run the project when it asks me for other dependencies that I'm no able to find in the web, and I have checked that those dependencies are not necessary because I checked my code and the (*.jar)'s in a project which doesn't use Maven and it works (without the necessity of importing that libs).

Comment: whats so wring with declaring a simple <dependency> on those jars? that is, after all, one of maven's main selling features - easy dependency handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: the following is only applicable when working in an environment where multiple people will share the same project. If you're on your own then all that has been suggested is just fine.

I'm not fond of system dependencies or doing local imports; in both cases you're still managing dependencies per machine and that is a burden Maven should be taking away from you.

If you really have a dependency that cannot be found in any online Maven repository, I would rather take the hard but more dependable route and that is to install a local Nexus server, which you can then also setup as a nice mirror for Maven central and the JBoss Nexus so clients don't have to keep downloading dependencies off of the internet. That way you have a single machine where all your Maven dependencies are maintained, which makes it nice and controllable. Plus your Nexus is more readily available; an external Maven source may go down or become unavailable should your internet connection drop.

You can then install your jars in the Nexus (in a local repository called 'third-party' is a common strategy I have seen used in the companies I have worked for so far) and your Maven clients, if properly told that your Nexus server is a mirror, can reference the third-party Maven dependencies as if they are coming from an online one.

Comment: You'll be thanking me more when you get to the advanced section on Maven called "release management", a Nexus is basically the foundation of getting that done reliably and easily :)

Answer (score 2):

You can import a jar to your local repository and reference it in the POM as usual. However, every developer needs to do the import on his/her machine (once).

see: http://jeff.langcode.com/archives/27

Comment: I'm going to try it!! Thanks a lot :D Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the goal on [maven-install-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html): `install-file`:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                     [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
                     [-Dsources=src.jar] \
                     [-Djavadoc=apidocs.jar] \
                     [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
                     [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
                     [-Dversion=1.0] \
                     [-Dpackaging=jar] \
                     [-Dclassifier=sources] \
                     [-DgeneratePom=true] \
                     [-DcreateChecksum=true]
```

If you are using [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), you can upload the jar [manually](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/repoman-sect-reasons.html#_deploy_3rd_party_artifacts).

Comment: Thank's @asgoth!! I gonna try it!! Have a nice day and thanks for your time and help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a [System Dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

Comment: I'm trying it!! I will tell you!! Thanks for your time and help!! Have a nice day. :D